# Android soundpool loop logic

Tags: android, loops, soundpool

I have two buttons which play soundpool files of the same priority in loop. Thus, if 1 button is playing in loop and the other one is pressed, this stops and other one starts playing in. 
Till here its fine. 
Now suppose i have each of the sound file of 2 seconds, and after pressing btn 2, the btn 1 should complete the  sound of the file 1, i.e for 2 secs it should play if has just started and stop. How can this be acheived?

Currently if I play btn2, the btn 1 stops playing at the moment where the file has not completed playing and starts file 2. I want the file 1 to be played completely before stopping.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that with sound pool, since sound pool doesn't has OnComletionListener or isPlaying method.

The only way you can achieve that by creating a new thread that listen for queue size and start the media player with new id when media player is not playing. Refer to the code below

```
private Queue<Integer> qSoundID;
private MediaPlayer mp;

private void init(){
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qSoundID.add(R.raw.yoursoundid);
        }
    });

    qSoundID = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (qSoundID.size() > 0) {
                    if(mp==null||!mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, qSoundID.poll());
                        mp.start();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Or set the OnCompletionListener on MediaPlayer that will play next sound id. Refer to the code below

```
private Queue<Integer> qSoundID;
private MediaPlayer mp;

private void init() {
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int soundID = R.raw.yoursoundid;
            playSound(soundID);
        }
    });
    qSoundID = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}

private void playSound(int soundID) {
    if (mp == null || !mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, soundID);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playSound(qSoundID.poll());
            }
        });
        mp.start();
    }
    else{
        qSoundID.add(soundID);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, this does not help since I am using the loop property of sound pool for a reason. I have many sounds which are of avg 2 secs and I want the next sound to take priority only when the current sound has finished playing (completed its 2 secs) in a loop. Thanks anyway!

Comment: while using media player, you can set loop too by calling MediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

Comment: then you can write your logic to play next sound on OnCompletionListener, hope this helps